# how to display the "advanced search" on the front page

Tags: advanced-search

How do I show the "advanced search" on the front page.
I want to open the website showing the advanced search options.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

First create this template file in your theme:

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalogsearch/advanced/home_form.phtml`.
Then copy the contents of the file `catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml` to your new file.
Replace

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSearchPostUrl() ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">
```

with

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result') ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">
```

Add this to your homepage content from CMS->Pages.

```
{{block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/home_form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: ,I followed you, search options are being shown on my home page, on performing search, it leads to result page, there it shows wrong no results(leave it), it shows just count, not results....like under **Catalog Advanced Search**, it says  10 item(s) were found using the following search criteria, 

    Name: star

Don't see what you're looking for? Modify your search, Am I missing some thing?

Comment: Would you help me please

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: **This is comment Not an Answer.** My is issue is this, before this there was no search option on home page. I make changes as you said. After that search option is available on home page as show in pic1, after performing search, result page is shown, on result page, result count is incorrect(that is logical issue, leave it for now), but searched product are now shown,just count is shown on page as you can see in pic2, this kills purpose of search.
[![pic1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JydyN.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JydyN.png)
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QhWw4.p

Comment: As I can't upload pic in comment, please see bellow details

Comment: Am I missing some thing?

Comment: please ask a different question explaining what the problem is.

Comment: @Marius I used the as you suggested , but problem is only "Catalog Advanced Search" heading and `search` button is shown no form input boxes.