# Display Advanced Search/Search on home page

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch, home, advanced-search

Currently  there is no search option on my home page, just categories are displayed. I tried to add search option by following [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/how-to-display-the-advanced-search-on-the-front-page)'s post, on Home page I got search option as shown in 1st pic, when I perform some search, On result page, I am getting just counts of founds(that are also not correct), not actual products,as shown in pic2, my question is that Am I missing some thing here? or is there an other way to do this(please guide me), I have also tried [Link](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/12039-Know-How-to-Add-Search-in-a-custom-CMS-Home-page-in-magento), this just  shows option for search, return no result

[image: pic1]

[image]

Comment: I think there is some kind of errors on the result page. Enable "error reporting" and "developer mode", then refresh the search result page. If error is there, please, update your question. PS: I reproduce all steps on my local Magento setup, and all works fine.

Comment: Please follow http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store and add additional informations as Siarhey said.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to just make the search page your home page? That can be easily achieved via the admin.