# “advanced search” shown on front page but no input boxes are shown Magento ver. 1.9.3.2

Tags: custom, forms, advanced-search, home-page, magento-1.9.3.2

I followed [Maris](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/how-to-display-the-advanced-search-on-the-front-page) post .

I copied the `C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\design\frontend\base\default\template‌​\catalogsearch\advan‌​ced\form.phtml`

to `C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\design\frontend\base\default\templat‌​e\catalogsearch\adva‌​nced\home_form.phtml`

To show on home page i used ( **am i wrong here** )

```
 <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="customname" template="catalogsearch/advanced/custom_form.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

[image: Form Code]

On Home Page Only Heading and search button is shown. 
When i click on search button it `redirects` me to `http://websitename.com/catalogsearch/advanced/`

Can any one see where i am doing wrong.

Thank You.

[image: Home Page]

Comment: @ post you code what you did

Comment: i copied the `C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalogsearch\advanced\form.phtml`  to `C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalogsearch\advanced\ home_form'

Comment: which magneto version you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.3.2

Comment: check template path hint your path is set?